# Is creating Android layout files for different DPIs necessary?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I recently downloaded some famous apks(like Instagram) and unzip them, I found out that they only contain single "layout" folder, however, Google advised using layout-hdpi,layout-xxhdpi to support different screens.

When I develop my own app I find if I use "xhpi ratio"(1dp = 3px), the app works fine for almost all devices(from 320*480 to 1080*1920).

And I'm using Android Studio under Windows now, the default structure only contains "layout" folder alone.

So, is it necessary to create different layout files to support different dpis? And what is right way to adapt the various android screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google advised using layout-hdpi,layout-xxhdpi to support different
>   screens

Where is it written? Usually **drawables** are put into directories with different density, but not layouts. Sometimes different layouts are created for different screen sizes (not density) and orientation (portrait, landscape).

Comment: Thanks, I got it wrong: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, Google says use large,xlarge for layout. But when the designers gave me an app design sketch with px, how do I convert it to dp? I use dp = px/3 now, does it right?

Comment: 1 px == 1 dp for screens with `mdpi` density, 3 px == 1 dp for screens with `xxhdpi`. If it looks good when you divide it with 3, then it means that designers designed for `xxhdpi`, and when you divide, you get sizes for `mdpi`: https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: you are right, the designers used 720*1280 resolution. Thank you very much, again.

Comment: I'm glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing several layouts when you are changing/updating your UI is a pain in the a.. Make your best to keep as min. number of layouts you need to maintain for your own good. Make one for phone, one for the tablet if you really must.

Comment: And maybe 1 for landscape/portrait too - if you support rotation, so to arrange the Views in an optimized way inside your layout for both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. I had done some apps with only one layout folder and also some  which has even 5 folders to perform well on different devices.
I have mindset that if i use Relativeayout, i won't have to use multiple screen. Its just according to me.
If you have observed instagram doesn't contain much complex design so may be they did not need to. as well as they only had to put things inside container(relative or linear) and the container are in order .

Comment: I only used RelativeLayout and LinearLayout and the drawable resources are pictures based on 720*1280. Do it mean if I set proper scaleTypes for all the ImageViews, I don't need to create different layout or drawable folders?

Comment: You should put wrap_content or match_parent anything like these.... don't give fix size to any. If your requirements are satisfied with these things, yes you wont have to create different layouts. Layouts are headache in android. :)

Comment: Thanks, "Avoid using exact size in Android unless you have to" :)